# Get Relationship Field Value Inside on Repeater going to Another Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

```
<?php

$related_articles = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'related_articles', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));


if( have_rows('related_articles_repeater') ): // i added this line im not sure about this
    while( have_rows('related_articles_repeater') ) : the_row();

    if( $related_articles ): 
        foreach( $related_articles as $article ): 

        // Do something to display the articles. Each article is a WP_Post object.
        // Example:

        echo $article->post_title;  // The post title
        echo $article->post_excerpt;  // The excerpt
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $article->ID );  // The thumbnail

        endforeach;
    endif;

endwhile;
endif;

?>
```

#### Hi guys! Whats wrong did i make? the code work well without repeater. I Wanted to work it with repeater so that i coded but is not working thougt.......................

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi theres is no error or what indication of error. but code is not working idk why